# Metrics about Prometheus Alerting

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

We have Prometheus & AlertManager in production and would like to have some Dashboards about when Alerts happened and when the Alert has gone away.

Are there some metrics about this "out of the box" - or do I have to implement something to achieve this? Something like a "MyAlertListener-Application" which offers a prometheus endpoint itself.

Answer (score 10):

Prometheus provides a synthetic time series called `ALERTS` which you can query and visualize for reasoning about alert states. See [the documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/#inspecting-alerts-during-runtime).

Comment: Looks promising, but it delivers no historical data. We would like to know data about alerts in retrospective, not only for the current point in time. Eg we want to know how many times a specific alert happened and how long it took the alert disappeared.

Comment: Why does it not deliver historical data? It's a Prometheus time series which contains samples for pending and firing alerts and their respective alert label combinations.