# What is a "synthetic time series" in Prometheus exactly?

Tags: time-series, prometheus

With a search engine I found [about synthetic time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922813/metrics-about-prometheus-alerting)

> Prometheus provides a synthetic time series called `ALERTS` which you
> can query and visualize for reasoning about alert states.

What is a "synthetic time series" in Prometheus exactly? What is the difference to "normal" time series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no established term "synthetic time series" in Prometheus.

It was used once in the documentation for this exact metric `ALERTS`, I can only assume to emphasize something. Most likely idea behind this, is that this metric is not scraped, but generated on the fly and put into database internally, similarly to metrics `up`.

As far as I can tell, it was introduced by [this commit](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/commit/f432b8176d0e69027ab46ad7ac434764da743a11#diff-a46c4028cdc3e176f65ef011d992ce74b30de9e3e1b590d02fed7eaa75646fbfR81) as part of general alerting rules documentation page.

Metric `ALERTS` behaves exactly as other "normal" time series: no need for any special considerations.